# Subcomponent value binded to the property of another instance of the same vue component

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, components, multiple-instances

I have an issue with a custom component. Here's the problem:

[image: Password show problem]

This screen is actually 3 times the same Vue component:

```html
<div class="passwords__form">
            <InputField class="passwords__field" label="Mot de passe actuel" :password="true" v-model="currentPassword" />
            <InputField class="passwords__field" label="Nouveau mot de passe" :password="true" v-model="newPassword" />
            <InputField class="passwords__field" label="Répéter le nouveau mot de passe" :password="true" v-model="repeatedPassword" />
            <Button title="Changer le mot de passe" @click="updatePassword"/>
</div>
```

Here's the component code:

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="field__container"
    :class="{ 'field__container--disabled': disabled }"
  >
    <label
      :for="this._uid"
      class="field__label"
      :class="{ 'field__label--disabled': disabled }"
      v-if="labelEnabled"
      >{{ label }}</label
    >
    <input
      :id="this._uid"
      class="field__input"
      :class="{
        'left-rounded': !labelEnabled && !password,
        'right-rounded': !buttonEnabled && !password
      }"
      :value="value"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
      @keyup.enter="$emit('keyup-enter')"
      :disabled="disabled"
      :type="fieldType"
    />
    <input
      v-if="password && enableShowPassword"
      type="checkbox"
      v-model="showPassword"
      id="password-checkbox"
      class="field__password-checkbox"
    /><label
      v-if="password && enableShowPassword"
      for="password-checkbox"
      class="field__password-checkbox-label"
      :class="{
        'right-rounded': !buttonEnabled,
      }"
    ><span v-if="enableShowPassword && showPassword"><EyeSlash class="field__password-checkbox-icon"/></span><span v-if="!showPassword" ><Eye class="field__password-checkbox-icon field__password-checkbox-icon--eye " /></span></label>
    <a
      v-if="buttonEnabled"
      class="field__button"
      @click.stop="$emit('button-click')"
    >
      {{ button }}
    </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import Vue from "vue";
import { Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
import Eye from "../assets/images/icons/eye-regular.svg"
import EyeSlash from "../assets/images/icons/eye-slash-regular.svg"

@Component({
  components: {
    Eye,
    EyeSlash
  }
})
export default class InputField extends Vue {
  @Prop({ default: "", required: false })
  label!: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  value!: string;

  @Prop({ default: "", required: false })
  placeholder!: string;

  @Prop({ default: "", required: false })
  button!: string;

  @Prop({ default: false, required: false })
  disabled!: boolean;

  @Prop({ default: false, required: false })
  password!: boolean;

  @Prop({ default: true, required: false })
  enableShowPassword!: boolean;

  showPassword = false;

  get fieldType(): string {
    if (this.password && !this.showPassword) {
      return "password";
    }
    return "text";
  }

  get labelEnabled(): boolean {
    return this.label !== "";
  }

  get buttonEnabled(): boolean {
    return this.button !== "";
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.field {
  &__container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid $color-grey-7;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    transition: all 0.3s;

    &:hover:not(&--disabled),
    &:focus:not(&--disabled) {
      border: 1px solid $color-complementary;

      & > .field__label {
        background: $color-complementary;
      }
    }

    &--disabled {
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
  }
  &__label {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    border-right: 1px solid $color-grey-8;
    background-color: $color-grey-8;
    transition: all 0.3s;

    &--disabled {
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
  }
  &__input {
    flex-grow: 2;
    border: none;

    color: $color-grey-1;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    padding: 0 1rem;

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
    }

    &--disabled {
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
  }

  &__button {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    border-left: 1px solid $color-grey-7;
    transition: all 0.3s;

    &:hover,
    &:active {
      background: $color-grey-7;
    }
  }

  &__password-checkbox {
    display: none;
  }

  &__password-checkbox-label {
    background-color: $color-grey-9;
    padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover,
    &:active {
      background-color: $color-complementary-lighter;
    }
  }

  &__password-checkbox-icon {
    width: 1.5rem;

    &--eye {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

I think the problem come from the `v-model` property on the checkbox. From what I see, the v-model binds to the `showPassword` property of the first instance of InputField, instead of binding to the current instance of InputField.

I'm not sure why it behaves like that and what my error is, and how to correct it/do it the right way. Does someone have any leads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should use an unique **id** for an input type="password" as you did for an usual input `:id="this._uid"` because on a HTML page all `id`'s declared in elements must be unique.